# How to get a value of a dynamic key in Groovy JSONSlurper?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

The variable `resp` contains below JSON response -

```
{"name":"sample","address":{"country":"IN","state":"TN","city":"Chennai"}}
```

I have planned using `param1` variable to get the required key from JSON response, but I'm unable to get my expected results.

I'm passing the `param1` field like - address.state

```
def actValToGet(param1){
    JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper();
    def values = slurper.parseText(resp)
    return values.param1 //values.address.state
}
```

I'm getting `NULL` value here -> `values.param1`

Can anyone please help me. I'm new to Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map returned from the `JsonSlurper` is nested rather than than flat. In other words, it is a map of maps (exactly mirroring the Json text which was parsed). The keys in the first map are `name` and `address`. The value of `name` is a String; the value of `address` is another map, with three more keys.

In order to parse out the value of a nested key, you must iterate through each layer. Here is a procedural solution to show what's happening.

```
class Main {
    static void main(String... args) {
        def resp = '{"name":"sample","address":{"country":"IN","state":"TN","city":"Chennai"}}'
        println actValToGet(resp, 'address.state')
    }

    static actValToGet(String resp, String params){
        JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def values = slurper.parseText(resp)
        def keys = params.split(/\./)
        def output = values
        keys.each { output = output.get(it) }
        return output
    }
}
```

A more functional approach might replace the mutable `output` variable with the `inject()` method.

```
    static actValToGet2(String resp, String params){
        JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def values = slurper.parseText(resp)
        def keys = params.split(/\./)
        return keys.inject(values) { map, key -> map.get(key) }
    }
```

And just to prove how concise Groovy can be, we can do it all in one line.

```
    static actValToGet3(String resp, String params){
        params.split(/\./).inject(new JsonSlurper().parseText(resp)) { map, key -> map[key] }
    }
```

You may want to set a debug point on the `values` output by the `parseText()` method to understand what it's returning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371329/jaco0646
Thanks a lot dude.
I have spent lot of hours to find the answer.

At last your and helped me.

Really thanks buddy