# Getting value from nested map in groovy using a nested key

Tags: groovy

Suppose I have nested map like this

```
def someMap = [
   a : [
      b : [
         c : "value",
         d : "anothervalue"
      ]
   ]
]
```

I get the key at runtime as a string.  Say it is "a.b.c"

How can I pull the value out of the map?

I know I can do myMap.a.b.c but for me, "a.b.c" is single string, I found out about at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052344/how-to-get-a-value-of-a-dynamic-key-in-groovy-jsonslurper

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180039/way-to-deep-traverse-a-groovy-object-with-dot-in-string-using-gpath

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157787/referencing-groovy-variable-as-part-of-json-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a value of a dynamic key in Groovy JSONSlurper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052344/how-to-get-a-value-of-a-dynamic-key-in-groovy-jsonslurper)

Comment: Do you know for sure that keys will never have a dot (`.`) in them?

Answer (score 0):

You could just go down the nodes likes this and try to get the respective child:

```
def key = "a.b.c"
def entry = someMap
key.split('\\.').each { entry = entry?.get(it) }
println entry?.value
```